# Executing Django Unit Tests with a Continuous integration server

Tags: django, unit-testing, jenkins, continuous-integration

This may seem like a very broad question, but i am really interested to know about possible approaches. Our team has a Django Web app and we have huge amount of unit tests for our features. Now in github, we have master branch, develop branch, and individual feature/bug branches. Now the problem i want to solve is,

Every time some code is merged into develop branch, i want to run all(or subset) of unit tests against that branch. It would be cool to have it automated, i-e i do not have to trigger the test run.

I have read and heard about Jenkins - http://michal.karzynski.pl/blog/2014/04/19/continuous-integration-server-for-django-using-jenkins/. Currently one of the approaches i am leaning towards.

But i wanted to know if there are better approaches or tools which i can use.

Appreciate all your help.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, you can't really go wrong with Jenkins for the functionality you are looking to achieve.

Although Travis CI may be a better option given that it's meant to work seamlessly with Github and it appears all of your repositories have been moved to Github.

Really depends on your business needs though.

Getting Jenkins up and running, from past experiences, has always gone very smoothly and it gives you the benefit of keeping all data in house as you have the option to host Jenkins on your own private servers but probably doesn't scale or run as efficiently as Travis CI does depending on your setup.

Travis CI will probably allow for an even more seamless approach because it's already being hosted for you and tied directly into Github, but you won't get the privacy as running Jenkins on your own servers.  There is a paid option though it appears for Travis CI which again, depending on your business needs, may be a better option.